# iOS: Tableview Begin updates never plays animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift

I have written some code to delete a post from the back end and local data storage when a user long presses a cell and confirms the change. However the tableview does not update.  I have breakpointed my code and the tableView manipulation code is executed, why is my row not being removed from the view?

```
let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Really?", message: "Are you sure you want to delete this post? Once you do it will be gone forever.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Delete Post", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (alertView:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        let p = post.getRawPost()
        p.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock({ (deleted:Bool, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            // Remove from the local datastore too
            p.fetchFromLocalDatastore()
            p.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock({ (deleted:Bool, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                // Update the table view
                self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Left)
                self.tableView.endUpdates()
        })

    })
}))
```

As I understand it, `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` is used to update specific sections of a tableView without needing to perform a full `reloadData` call on the source.  Am I missing something here?

**UPDATE** I moved the tableView update code to the main thread, this produced a crash whenever `endUpdates` is called.  My new code looks as below, and is called on the main thread:

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row, inSection: indexPath.section)], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the code snippet below in **MAIN THREAD** instead:

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Left)
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

---

#### EDIT for the crash

```
p.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock({ (deleted:Bool, error:NSError?) -> Void in
   // Remove from the local datastore too
   p.fetchFromLocalDatastore()

   // Delete the desired item from array
   ...
   // Remove cell that the item belong to animated in main thread
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
       // Update the table view
       self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Left)
   })
})
```

Comment: Hmm I moved it onto the main thread, and now it crashes my application. Any idea why this could be happening? The stack trace isn't too helpful

Comment: @Alex i think u can just rm the `self.tableView.beginUpdates()` & `self.tableView.endUpdates()`, the middle one should works well in main thread animated.

Comment: Removing begin and end updates still causes the application to crash.

Comment: @Alex make sure the desired item has been removed before removing the cell. Plz take a look at the updated answer :)

Comment: Perfect, dispatching on the main queue fixed the problem. I always thought using `self` references the main queue my bad!   Thanks for your help :)