# Reload table after alert Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I'm trying to reload my tableView after an object is deleted from Parse.
I try `self.tableView.reloadData()` in my completion handler and even get a `print` statement that tells me when it's done but my table doesn't reload.

```
@IBAction func trashButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        print("Button pressed")

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Do you want to delete all recent games?", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { (action) in

        }

        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { (action) in

            for game in self.games[3] {
                game.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {

                        self.tableView.reloadData()

                        print("Did delete game? \(success)")
                    }
                })
            }
        }

        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        alertController.addAction(OKAction)

        presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in
            print("Alert was shown")
        })

    }
```

**What am I doing wrong?  Where should I put `self.tableView.reloadData()`?**

**EDIT**

I tried to get the main queue like so:

```
  game.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error) -> Void in
                if error == nil {

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    })

                    print("Did delete game? \(success)")
                } else {

                    print("Error: \(error)")
                }
            })
```

The table still did not reload when I pressed `OK`

Comment: At least call `reloadData()` on the main thread.

Comment: I have no experience with Parse, but according to https://parse.com/questions/what-thread-does-findobjectsinbackgroundwithblock-complete-on, all completion blocks execute on the main thread. On the other hand, here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29879884/ios-tableview-begin-updates-never-plays-animation it is claimed that you need to dispatch to  the main thread.

Answer (score 2):

You may see this behavior if `-deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:` doesn't call your block on the main thread. It's reasonable to assume you'd want to execute your block on the background too. I found it in the Parse documentation, but it doesn't state whether it returns on the main thread.

If this is indeed the problem, you can fix it like this:

```
game.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PFQueryTableViewController you can try to call

```
loadObjects()
```

instead of `self.tableView.reloadData()`

Answer (score 0):

I have used defer { ... } after deleteInBackgroundWithBlock, so it's actually worked for my situation.

```
object.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock(nil)

defer {
     array = [] // remove all object in the array that you query before
     queryParse() // query new object from Parse (without deleted object)
     tableView.reloadData() // reload tableView
  }
```